# What is the preferred way of passing an array of small objects from Java to native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Given a simple Java class like this:

```
class MyData {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public int d;
}
```

And a `MyData data[]` that I need to pass into native code, is it better to do something like this:

```
for (MyData item : data) {
    myNativeMethod(item.a,item.b,item.c,item.d);
}
```

Or is it better to `myNativeMethod(data)` and use `GetArrayLength`, `GetObjectArrayElement` and `GetIntField`?

In this case "better" is intentionally vague.  Performance and maintainability are both concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case it's simpler to pass individual values as parameters. However, it will clutter your Java code once the object gets more complex.

Said that, I don't see huge difference to prefer one way over another.